# Feasibility of linking the libev + http server + libtls

Tags: c++, c, httpserver, libev

I think, I got lost.

The problem is that I want to use **event-loop** based approach to implement simple **HTTPS server** (TLS 1.x). From what I've read so far, the best candidate to build an event loop is `libev` and the best candidate nowadays to work with TLS is [`libtls`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/tls_accept_fds.3?query=tls_init&sec=3) from the [**LibreSSL Project**](http://www.libressl.org/).

I do know that `libev` doesn't contain DNS and HTTP server (as opposed to `libevent`) so I have to either find another library that will add this capability or use implement it by myself. I found [`http-parser`](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser) library that can help me with that.

Regarding the TLS thing, I believe the LibreSSL's `libtls` can be fit in without any problem, because it actually doesn't matter what kind of byte string you are processing.

So the main question is: am I right thinking that way? Is it really possible to use `libev` + `http-parser` + `libtls` in order to build event-loop based HTTPS server? Is is feasible to implement it at all? Am I missing smth important? Could you recommend other libraries which can help me implement HTTP server?

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds feasible, and it sounds pretty simple too. Just find a tcp echo server example for libev and make it use libtls, then add in the http-parser. It sounds like it would take a few days to get started, but once you had all of the code written, you just have to add some config options.

Comment: Thanks, Nunzio. I've already made some progress, and once I finish, I will update the questions here.

Comment: Why have not you try libuv instead of libev?

Comment: @dlmeetei, not sure. The question was asked a long time ago and honestly I don't remember why I decided to choose libev ;) But if you ask now, I would recommend to go with native and write for each platform different layer using the only native tools. Why? I do have a working sample of streaming server that works just amazingly fast and it was written natively and optimized. However, I might be wrong.